# Express & socket.io > v1.0

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I m trying to create a simple application in which I need to use Socket.IO with a version > 1.0 (so without using express.io...)

So what is the best way to use express > 4.0 and socket.io >1.0 with the best scalability possibilities ?

Should I put the socket.io connexion event inside my app routing events ? Should I put my app routing events inside the socket.io connexion event ?

Thank for advance

Answer (score 1):

This [post](http://verwebbt.de/2014/11/30/socket-io-in-an-express-app/) probably answers your question as it did mine :-)